# Using HMAC with AES modes that do NOT require padding

Tags: aes, symmetric, hmac, authenticated-encryption, perfect-secrecy

I'm trying to use HMAC with AES modes that do not require any sort of padding.
Although I am aware that modes like `AES-GCM` and `AES-EAX` already provide
authentication, I want to know if HMAC is suitable with the modes that do not
provide any authentication. This is what I tried:

## The code

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
import hmac


class DecryptionError(Exception):
    pass


class AESNonAEAD:
    def __init__(self, is_encrypting, key, mode, iv_or_nonce, digestmod='sha256'):
        self._is_encrypting = is_encrypting

        # Use KDF to derive key material from given key:
        # length of crp == length of key
        # length of authkey == (digest size of hashalgo for HMAC // 8)
        crpkey, authkey = derive_key_material(key, digestmod)

        self._auth = hmac.new(authkey, digestmod=digestmod)
        self._cipher = AES.new(key, mode, iv_or_nonce)
        if is_encrypting:
            self._update = self._cipher.encrypt
        else:
            self._update = self._cipher.decrypt

        self._auth.update(iv_or_nonce)

        self._updated = False
        self._len_ct = 0
        self._len_aad = 0

    def authenticate(self, data):
        if self._updated:
            raise ValueError('update has already been called')
        self._auth.update(data)
        self._len_aad += len(data)

    def _pad_aad(self):
        # pad to a multiple of 16 bytes
        if self._len_aad & 0x0F:
            self._auth.update(bytes(16 - (self._len_aad & 0x0F)))

    def update(self):
        if not self._updated:
            self._pad_aad()
            self._updated = True

        if not self._is_encrypting:
            self._auth.update(data)

        res = self._update(data)
        self._len_ct += len(res)

        if self._is_encrypting:
            self._auth.update(res)
        return res

    def finalize(self, tag=None):
        if not self._is_encrypting and tag is None:
            raise ValueError('tag is required')

        # pad to a multiple of 16 bytes
        if self._len_ct & 0x0F:
           self._auth.update(bytes(16 - (self._len_ct & 0x0F)))
        # include length of aad and ciphertext
        self._auth.update(self._len_aad.to_bytes(8, 'little'))
        self._auth.update(self._len_ct.to_bytes(8, 'little'))

        if self._is_encrypting:
            return
        if not hmac.compare_digest(tag, self._auth.digest()):
            raise DecryptionError

    def calcuate_tag(self):
        if self._is_encrypting:
            return self._hmac.digest()
```

---

## Usage

### Encryption

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

key = os.urandom(32)
iv = os.urandom(16)
enc = AESNonAEAD(True, key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)  # or MODE_CTR

enc.authenticate(b'yes this')
encdata = enc.update(b'no not this')
enc.finalize()
tag = enc.calculate_tag()
```

---

### Decryption

```
dec = AESNonAEAD(False, key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)  # or MODE_CTR

dec.authenticate(b'yes this')
decdata = dec.update(encdata)
```

---

## Questions:

- Is this implementation acceptable?
- Is this the proper way of using HMAC? Is it necessary to pad the HMAC for non padded cipher modes?
- Can this very same scheme be used with Camellia cipher?

Comment: If the code is working then it can be acceptable. that is a broad question. We are not codereview'ing rather we are accepting some code to demonstrate the usage.

Comment: @keralaka Working code is different from cryptographically secure implementation. And I chose Python as my demonstration of an implementation. My question was, is this implementation secure from a cryptographic point of view?

Comment: I've closed this question. This is about debugging your implementation of an AEAD construction. Furthermore, you keep updating the question once you've been made aware of possible security issues, and as such the answers do not remain valid and are confusing to any other readers.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes so, should I delete this question?

Comment: That's up to you, I guess readers should be considered warned by my comment above. If  I thought it needed direct deletion than I would have deleted it. Leaving it open keeps it around for a bit of commenting whatnot, but eventually it will probably get deleted anyway.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes my confusion was in the point that, do I need to pad the HMAC's input, if the cipher's input do not require padding? Please note that the cipher will be used continuously over a large amount of data.

Comment: No, that seems spurious, as the HMAC will perform the padding itself (and it also contains the length of the input). You could actually gain some speed if you make sure that the hash operations have some space left in the final input block of the hash. Also, the block size of hash functions (and therefore the HMAC) are relatively large: 512 bits for SHA-256 and 1024 bits for SHA-512. So padding up to 16 bytes does nothing. However, the AAD, IV and ciphertext do need to be encoded in a canonical form if you're planning to use a single HMAC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110890/discussion-between-arunanshub-and-maarten-bodewes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your input to HMAC is the ciphertext $c$, padded with null bytes (to a multiple of 16 bytes):

```
    # pad to a multiple of 16 bytes
    if self._len_ct & 0x0F:
       self._auth.update(bytes(16 - (self._len_ct & 0x0F)))
```

As a concrete example, suppose the ciphertext is $c=$ `deadbeef00`, then you will compute the HMAC tag as $t = $ HMAC(`deadbeef0000...00`), 16 bytes. But this is also a valid HMAC tag for different ciphertexts $c'=$ `deadbeef` as well as $c' =$ `deadbeef000000` etc. I hope you can see why this breaks the authenticated encryption security property.

I'm not sure why you are padding/encoding the HMAC input in this way, but my guess is you are trying to "serialize" both the ciphertext and associated data into a single string that is given to HMAC.  This is a common pitfall for authentication: you want to authenticate a pair of things $(x,y)$, and so you authenticate the string $x \| y$. But many pairs $(x',y')$ get mapped to the same string  $x\|y$ (think of cases where the length of $x$, $y$ are variable)! In order to properly authenticate, you need an *unambiguous* encoding of the pair $(x,y)$ into a string. One good way would be to somehow include the length of $x$ as part of this encoding.

**edit:** also you never seem to use `self._cipher`?

Comment: So you say I should include the length of AAD and Ciphertext as well? I edited and fixed the code accordingly. Is it really necessary to pad the HMAC for modes other than CBC?